# Android Studio not showing running abv in device list any one have solution?

Tags: android, android-studio, dart

I have tried every possible solution nothing is working. Even reset my entire setup still same issue
tried updating all packages, avd manager, cmd-adb device check,etc.
really need help!

Answer (score 0):

You might have an existing adb process running in your system.
Kill that process in your task manager.

Use a physical device and see if that shows up in your list of available devices.

Create a 2nd virtual device from AVD and delete the previous one.

Comment: Thanks but did that to.

But never mind found the solution
"had to remove android studio and install visual studio for all the packages and avd then install android studio selecting the folder where visual studio installed all the packages .
Everything worked then.